# Nest-API: Nest Protect and Nest Thermostat Occupancy Sensor Data

Tags: nest-api

Is it possible to access data about the occupancy sensor on the nest Protect and Thermostat? Ie last recorded occupancy event?

I've had a look on the API-reference but I've had no luck:
https://developers.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/